# Problems with setting text to a textField

Tags: java, client-server, jtextfield, configuration-files

I am creating a client-server chat application and I intend required to store the username for a better user experience.As soon as I fire the main method, the load() method is called.This method sets the user name automatically by reading from the configurations file.The configuration file is not null (I have the user name stored). But the textField is not updating.Any ideas?Here is my load method:

```
public static void load()
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        textField.setText(prop.getProperty("user"));  //not updating!!!!

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of _config.properties_ ?

Comment: In cases like this, start with much simpler code - replace all code in the `load()` method with something like `textField.setText("IsThisTextShown?");`. Then, verify if this succeeds - you will see if it is an issue with the property file or with the text field. Also, why is the method `static`? You should add a [mcve].

Comment: I did that.But still the textField isn't updating.Is there any harm is using static?I generally do this as it simplifies the coding process for me a bit.

Comment: Here are the contents of the configuration file:#Wed Mar 02 20:11:51 IST 2016
user=prashant

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Andreas Fester said above. You should first do a check on the file, if it exists or not, this will allow you to verify you are pointing to the right directory in the case the root of the project. Also add a clause saying something like `if(prop.getProperty("user")==null){//handle null}` then also try using `textField.append("text");` just to see a different method and then verify by doing `System.out.println("TextField: "+textField.getText())` to see if it is setting the text

If anything look at [this demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java) given by oracle to use textfield. Also its a good practice to know when to separate member variable (belongs to instance) or class variables(static), I would avoid static like in the demo provided.

hope this helps.

Comment: I removed the entire contents of the load() method and replaced it with 'textField.setText("Jack").But it still does not work.

Comment: did you check what textField.getText() returns?

Comment: also post your code where you are adding it to the JPanel etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, guys.I figured out the problem.Actually, I had declared textfield as:

static JTextField textField=new JTextField();

outside main() and then again as:

textField=new JTextField();

inside the constructor.I removed the one inside the constructor and it solved the problem.

Once again thank you all for your help.

Comment: I just edited my answer to point you towards the non static direction, good work!